# c3.js how to display values inside/at the top of the bars

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I've been searching the c3.js reference but couldn't find any setting that I can make the values appear in the bars.  It's cool to have tooltips but it's easier in my situation to display values directly in the bar columns...

Comment: Refer to following example:- http://c3js.org/samples/data_label.html

Comment: Nice.  Is there any way to put the label in the center of the bar?  It looks odd in a stacked bar chart... See https://jsfiddle.net/tom15375/fy3tm98d/

Answer (score -1):

You need to override certiain c3.js internal_functions to provide desired x,y corordinate values for the  svg element which contains bar values as shown below:-

[image]

Comment: You don't need to override c3's source. Instead of that you can just add `labels: true` to data in your `c3.generate`.